# Is there any way to configure wireless settings for all access points in the network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wpa2

I have a fairly large house, with a main router (Asus) that handles the internet connection as well as DHCP, firewall, etc. This router is connected to an ethernet switch, which is connected to different areas in the house as a sort of "backbone". Multiple WiFi access points (different brands) are then connected to the ethernet network (about 4-5) and so I have full WiFi coverage around the house. All WiFi access points currently share the same SSID

Unfortunately, it's an insecure network. I now want to set some security, but that involves having to set each single access point one by one, and I would have to make sure that the settings all match. I could do it manually, but I'm wondering if there's a way to automate this. Can one router manage the settings of the other routers in the house?

I'm pretty sure this is possible, because there are places like universities, office workplaces, etc. that all seem to have a unified WiFi configuration. Those must have tens to hundreds of access points managed by one IT team, so I'm pretty sure they are using some kind of system to set the settings on them all whenever they need to. Is this a standard and is it possible on your average home router?

Comment: It's unlikely that you can easily automate the configuration of multiple brands of routers at once.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you cannot do this with the different brand access points in your house.

What Universities/Offices/Hotels will use is one single brand of access point, that can be managed from one location.

If you want to invest some money, I'd look into the Ubiquiti Line of Access Points.

[Their Wifi Products Listed Here](https://www.ubnt.com/products/#enterprise/wireless)

The range on these devices is very nice, and there is a free downloaded for the controller software, where you can manage one/all APs in one place.  They all come with a POE (Power over Ethernet) injector, so you could power all your Access Points from your switch area.

Comment: I see. Unfortunate... but thanks for the link. I'll keep these in mind next time I want to make an upgrade... but at this point probably never :) alternatively I might be able to write a script that automates using http or telnet or something..